# Brightness stuck at full after suspend HP Pavilion G6 12.04

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, suspend, brightness, hp

I have an ongoing problem with my linux install where brightness seems to get stuck at full after my laptop suspends. Before suspend, the hotkeys work fine. After suspend the hotkeys still bring up the brightness indicator, but despite the bar going up and down, the brightness doesn't actually change. Likewise, the terminal commands don't have any effect. I've tried all sorts of different settings in grub but that only seems to disable my ability to change the brightness entirely. Are there any other ideas out there or any options I have to narrow down what the issue might be?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with 14.04 on an Asus X201-E.

Comment: @user208026 This will sound a little strange, but please do me a favor:  After suspend, when the hotkeys do not work, log out of your system and log back in.  Please report if the hotkeys work after loggin back in.  I have a similar issue with a Dell, and have not yet traced down why this works for me.

Comment: @CharlesGreen For me, the issue is now only happening after disconnecting from an external monitor (unrelated to suspend) and it does resolve itself if I log out and log back in.

Comment: @user208026 I recently loaded `sudo apt-get install intel-microcode` and I can no longer reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 14.04 kernel 3.15rc2 I can't reproduce the issue, and as 12.04 is out of support I'm closing this

Comment: Working on the cutting edge!